# How to turn multiple servos by an angle using the Adafruit servo/pwm pi hat?

Tags: servo, hat

So I'm using a Raspberry Pi Model 3b and an Adafruit 12-bit PWM Servo/PWM Pi Hat on my project to control 6 independent continuous servos. I'd like to send in signals that would turn the servo by that definite angle.
I saw docs that let me calculate the servo angle and send in the signals but all of them do it on a single servo motor by using the GPIO pins and changing the duty cycle. Now, while using the piHat, is there a way for me to use the changeDutyCycle() function and thus control the 6 servo motors precisely?

Comment: You can't command continuous servos to an angle.  Do you mean normal servos?  Of course you can set the dutycycle independently.  Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: @joan I meant servos that turn have 360 degree rotation. In particular I'm using this [servo](http://hitecnology.hitecrcd.com/servo-actuators/20mm-class/hsr-m9382th-20mm-brushless-wmagnetic-encoder-titanium-gear-360-10-turn-wproportional-control-servo-actuator/product). I use the setPWM command from Adafruit library as shown [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi/library-reference). 
I'd like to know how could I define a function (setAngle) that would turn it to a specific angle, say 90, if I give a command setAngle(90).